# C# Dynamically Move Picturebox Class With Mouse

Tags: c#, dynamic, picturebox

I'm currently trying to make a video game level editor and am trying to have it where the user can add objects to the screen and then manipulate their locations and sizes and what not. I'm starting off by just having a platform class, and this is the method I'm using to allow the user to edit the location of the platforms:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LevelEditor
{
    class Platform : PictureBox
    {

        private PictureBox platform = new PictureBox();

        public Platform(int width, int height, int x, int y)
        {
            platform.Width = width;
            platform.Height = height;
            platform.Location = new Point(x, y);
            platform.BackColor = Color.Red;
            platform.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        }

        public void drawTo(Form form)
        {
            form.Controls.Add(platform);
        }

        public void setPosition(int x, int y)
        {
            platform.Location = new Point(x, y);
        }

        private Point MouseDownLocation;

        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseDown(e);
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseMove(e);

            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                platform.Left = e.X + platform.Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
                platform.Top = e.Y + platform.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that it's not working. I know that the `Platform` is not even detecting the MouseDown event because I've debugged it. I'm not sure what the problem is and any help is appreciated!

Comment: When you add a new instance of Platform Picture box -- do you assign its MouseDown & Move Events. You got to Assign the Event when creating the object of Platform. Something like: Platform obj = new new Platform();   then =>  obj.MouseDown += new event.... VS intellisense will help you with syntax the moment you type +=

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava What new event would I add after obj.MouseDown += new event? I don't want to create a new event, I already made the MouseDown event in the class...

Comment: Yes so attach the same. the syntax will be obj.MouseDown += new event (YouMethodHere).... This is assuming your Method matches the delegate - which it does not. because Events have a sender & event args 2 arguments from memory.

Comment: Irrelevant to the question - Why is your Platform class Inheriting as well as Composing PictureBox. It has to be One of those. Your Platform class at the moment is a Type of PictureBox which also Contains a PictureBox DataMember.

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava that actually just solved my problem, thanks!

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava you should really post an answer, to let everyone know its solved. You might even get some rep points...

Comment: @JeremyThompson - Thank you :) - I will do so. I reply here as & when I find time from my workplace.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was, as pointed out in the comments, I was inheriting from Picturebox, but using an instance of a Picturebox variable as the object itself. The corrected code is this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LevelEditor
{
    class Platform : PictureBox
    {

        public Platform(int width, int height, int x, int y)
        {
            this.Width = width;
            this.Height = height;
            this.Location = new Point(x, y);
            this.BackColor = Color.Red;
            this.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        }

        public void drawTo(Form form)
        {
            form.Controls.Add(this);
        }

        public void setPosition(int x, int y)
        {
            this.Location = new Point(x, y);
        }

        private Point MouseDownLocation;

        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseDown(e);
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseMove(e);

            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                this.Left = e.X + this.Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
                this.Top = e.Y + this.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
            }
        }
    }
}
```